# React Native Infinity Installation on Android Device

Tags: android, react-native, terminal

I am using nfirebase.io Starter Kit and  after a successful launch on the IOS, I have an infinite install on Android

After

> react-native run-android

I Have

> JS server already running. Building and installing the app on the
>   device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)... Checking the license
>   for package Android SDK Platform 24 in
>   /Users/voody/Library/Android/sdk/licenses License for package Android
>   SDK Platform 24 accepted. Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 24".
>
> > Configuring > 2/3 projects

And for 40 minutes nothing happens

Comment: After one hour everything is okay!